# Import a shared object and call its functions in C++

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

Is it possible to import a shared object (without linking the program with it) and call any function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

- Windows: use [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175(VS.85).aspx) and [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212(v=VS.85).aspx).
- POSIX: use [dlopen](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html) and [dlsym](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html).
  There is a [mini tutorial here](http://ehuss.com/shared/).

Comment: I'm using Linux. I made a simple shared object with a the function "void say_hello()", I could import it without errors with dlopen(), but how can I call the say_hello function?

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly. Here is my test: http://eduardo38.netne.net/dlopen_test.tar.gz